# Driver for Canon LBP 2900

Tags: printing, 14.04, canon

How do I install the driver for Canon LBP 2900 printer in Ubuntu 14.04?

I have tried installing drivers from the official CANON support and checked other answers on Ask Ubuntu but so far no results.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/463289/cant-get-my-canon-lbp-printer-to-run-under-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: I downloaded the last drivers and tried to restart cups but it doesn't work. Everything looks ok, I can see my printer if I go in "settings" but it says it is inactive and it doesn't print. Any other ideas?

Comment: There have been some effort for an out-of-the-box script here : https://github.com/dkavraal/CanonCAPTdriver (CAPT 2.60)

Comment: See also: [Can't get my Canon LBP printer to run under Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/463289/cant-get-my-canon-lbp-printer-to-run-under-ubuntu-14-04/464334#464334) and The [community Ubuntu 13.10 Install](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190?action=show&redirect=HardwareSupportComponentsPrinters%2FCanonPrinters%2FCanon_LBP_2900#Adding_a_printer)

Comment: Ok... this previous git repos have poor review for 14.04.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me in Linux Mint 17 32-bit (which is more or less Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit).

1. Download and install the drivers.

   Go to the Canon Asia website (or any other Canon website) and download the CAPT Printer Driver for Linux Version 2.60 from [this link](http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100459601.html).

   Extract it to get a folder containing directory 32-bit_Driver/Debian, enter inside.

   Install the .deb file cndrvcups-common_2.60-1_i386.deb from the terminal:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i cndrvcups-common_2.60-1_i386.deb
   ```

   You may also install it using gdebi package installer.

   Next install cndrvcups-capt_2.60-1_i386.deb

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i cndrvcups-capt_2.60-1_i386.deb
   ```
2. Install other postscript fonts and program to reserve ports for the printer.

   Install portreserve, gsfonts, gsfonts-other, gsfonts-X11 via Synaptic Package Manager.
3. Restart the printer.

   ```
   service cups restart
   ```
4. Add printer and start the Canon Printer daemon.

   ```
   sudo /usr/sbin/lpadmin -p LBP2900 -m CNCUPSLBP2900CAPTK.ppd -v ccp://localhost:59787 -E  
   sudo /usr/sbin/ccpdadmin -p LBP2900 -o /dev/usb/lp0
   sudo service ccpd start
   sudo service ccpd status
   ```
5. Check the printer status.

   ```
   captstatusui -P LBP2900
   ```

   If you are seeing the message `Ready to print`, you are done! Else you may have to restart the system, and repeat all the steps from step 4.

   It may cease to work after restarting the system. Run `sudo service ccpd restart` and try again.

Comment: I did exactly that and failed. Ubuntu 14.04, 64bits.

Comment: Note that I tried this on Ubuntu 20.04. It worked only after changing `-m CNCUPSLBP2900CAPTK.ppd` to `-P /usr/share/cups/model/CNCUPSLBP2900CAPTK.ppd` (full path, as indicated in the instructions from Canon) in the `lpadmin` command. Do also notice that the printer might not be registered as `lp0`, especially if you're adding/removing the printer for testing, so check the number by using `ls /dev/usb/lp*`.

Answer (score 5):

Below is my working solution, adaptable for other LBP models & PC bitwidths.

#### Install

In the case of Ubuntu 64-bit, printer Canon LBP2900:

```
git clone https://github.com/hugolpz/Canon_printer.git
cd ./Canon_printer
make -f ./download.mk
sudo make -f ./install.mk BITS=64 PRINTER=LBP2900
sudo make -f ./OS_restart.mk
sudo make -f ./install.mk BITS=64 PRINTER=LBP2900
```

Adapt to your bitwidth.

#### OS restart

If printer is not working after install & OS restart :

```
sudo pkill -9 -x ccpd
sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd start   # Output should have 2 numbers of 4 digits !
> Canon Printer Daemon for CUPS: ccpd: 2626 2615    # seems good :)
```

For more instructions, see https://github.com/hugolpz/Canon_printer

#### Recommendations

Buy a non-Canon Linux compatible printer.

Comment: When run sudo make -f ./install.mk BITS=64 PRINTER=LBP2900 : gzip: drivers.tar.gz: not in gzip format
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
install.mk:36: recipe for target 'unzip' failed
make: *** [unzip] Error 2

Answer (score 1):

This is the latest driver from canon.  Its version 2.60, and you can download it [here](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/6/0100004596/03/Linux_CAPT_PrinterDriver_V260_uk_EN.tar.gz).

Once extracted it will have both the 32bit drivers, and the 64bit drivers.

This software is a CAPT printer driver that provides printing functions for Canon LBP printers operating under the CUPS (Common UNIX Printing System) environment, a printing system that operates on Linux operating systems.

Comment: I already did that, i know that in previous version there is some steps to restart cups etc via terminal, do you know the full guide for installing ?

Comment: To restart CUPS from terminal you would `sudo /etc/init.d/cupsys restart`

Comment: I need answer for http://askubuntu.com/q/519521/155039