# Install canon lbp 2900b printer on my clients system

Tags: 14.04, printing, canon

I have recently installed Ubuntu on my system to start learning Linux.

My boss has challenged me to install Canon lbp 2900b on my computer. I have Googled many pages but none of them are working fine for me. Many of the commands are giving me some dependency errors.

I'm not much versed with programming knowledge, please can anyone help me with simple instructions and tutorial.

Comment: 1st try this: https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/canon-trunk and please report back if it does or does not work :)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/457774/driver-canon-lbp-2900