# Canon Laser Shoot - LBP 1210 not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, printing, canon

I've installed the latest version and it's fine but not sure why it's not working. I'm giving some screen shots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What driver did you install?

Comment: The official canon driver 2.6, I followed https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190 but stuck at Ubuntu 14.04 Install

Comment: It says "After you've added the printer it most likely will not print anything, even though cups sees it." May be this is the problem but can't solve it.

Comment: Have you tried a different USB port, or USB cable?

Comment: No problem with USB I can print with Win XP

Comment: Try this: `stop cups`, replace `printers.conf` with `printers.conf.O`, and then `start cups` again.

Comment: How will I do that, I'm not so expert in ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo -i
stop cups
mv /etc/cups/printers.conf.O /etc/cups/printers.conf
start cups
```

Comment: Not working. Same as screen shots, Unable to send data to printer. It's detecting, installing driver but not printing. Why it's unable to send data to printer?