# Canon LBP 2900 not working on ubuntu 14.04 error message devicepath

Tags: printing, canon

I did the following:

1. Downloaded and installed CAPT drivers v 2.6 with dpkg.
2. Installed `portreserve`, `gsfonts`, `gsfonts-other`, `gsfonts-X11` with `apt-get`.
3. Ran `sudo service cups restart`.
4. Then

   ```
   sudo /usr/sbin/lpadmin -p LBP2900 -m CNCUPSLBP2900CAPTK.ppd -v ccp://localhost:59787 -E
   ```
5. Ran `sudo /usr/sbin/ccpdadmin -p LBP2900 -o /dev/usb/lp0`
6. Ran `sudo service ccpd start`
7. Ran `sudo service ccpd status`
8. Ran `captstatusui -P LBP290` and got an error message in a window with the title LBP 2900:

   ```
   Check the DevicePath of /etc/ccpd.conf
   ```

The `DevicePath` line in `/etc/ccpd.conf` says: `/dev/usb/lp0`

When I checked `/dev/usb`, I found only `lp1` there, so I changed the entry in the `DevicePath` line to `/dev/usb/lp1`.

No difference to the results.

No printing done.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Same here, ubuntu 14.04, 64bits. after following : http://askubuntu.com/questions/457774/driver-canon-lbp-2900