# cCanon LBP2900 Printer installation problem in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, printing, canon

My printer was working on Ubuntu 16.04, but after installation it isn't working in Ubuntu 18.04 even after reinstalling the drivers `cndrvcups-capt_2.71-1_amd64.deb` and `cndrvcups-common_3.21-1_amd64.deb`.

Comment: Have you reinstalled the drivers? When asking please always try to post complete information.

Comment: yes re installed drivers cndrvcups-capt_2.71-1_amd64.deb and cndrvcups-common_3.21-1_amd64.deb

Comment: Also please always [edit] your questions whenever you need to add additional information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Driver for Canon LBP 2900](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457774/driver-for-canon-lbp-2900)